# SQL Group By function(column) - Now can't Select that column

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, ora-00979

I used the HR employee schema in Oracle Express and I wanted to select employees that were hired on a particular year.

```
  SELECT hire_date, 
         COUNT(*)
    FROM employees empl
GROUP BY SUBSTR(hire_date, -4)
ORDER BY empl.hire_date;
```

The hire_date column has this format "1/1/2011" so I'd like to group them
by extracting the last four char.

Problem is, I am encountering below error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 7
```

Is this not possible?

Comment: Is the hire_date column a date or a character type? The output from: 'describe employees' will tell you this.

Comment: Why are you using `substr()` on a `date` column? substr() is for varchar columns. If you need to get parts of a date, you should use `to_char()` (or extract) instead. You are relying on implicit data conversion that is bound to break if the locale settings are changed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks.  Its my first time to work with Oracle DB but I have put this in my TODO list.  Appreciate your input.. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't select the full `hire_date` if you're *grouping* by only the last four digits of it. Think of what will happen if you have the two rows:

```
hire_date
=========
01/01/2001
02/02/2001
```

In the *single* row generated when you group those, what should the `hire_date` be?

Every column selected must either be a group-by column or an aggregate column. In other words, try:

```
select substr(hire_date,-4), count(*)
from employees
group by substr(hire_date,-4)
order by empl.hire_date;
```

---

I should mention that per-row functions are notoriously bad at scaling. If you want to process the year a lot, you should consider splitting it into its own column. That may greatly improve performance, but *measure, don't guess!*

And, as others have mentioned in comments, `substr` is probably not the best solution since that may depend on locale (as in: it may be possible for the date to be formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` which will not go well with the `substring`).

It may be better to use something like `to_char(hire_date,'YYYY')` or `extract (year from hire_date)` which should be more robust.

Comment: And you should also mention that doing a SUBSTR on a date is a VERY bad idea (as already mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name). "group by extract(year from hire_date)" is the way to go.

Comment: @Rob, yes, assuming it _is_ a date column. It may be a char/varchar, which is a _different_ problem :-)

Comment: It is a date column. It's the standard HR schema.

Answer (score 7):

you can also truncate the hiredate column

```
select trunc(hiredate, 'yyyy'), count(*) 
from employee
group by trunc(hiredate, 'yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want group employees by the year they were hired in use

```
select to_char(hiredate,'yyyy'),count(*) 
from employee
group by to_char(hiredate,'yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `GROUP BY` conditions or aggregate functions (`MIN, MAX, AVG`, etc.) in the `SELECT` part of a `GROUP BY` query. This works:

```
select substr(hire_date,-4), count(*)
from employees empl
group by substr(hire_date,-4)
order by substr(hire_date,-4);
```